# What are the rules i need to follow when writing for the piano?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

Okay so i recently discovered writing in 4 part harmony and now i'm really confused, i saw people say that you don't need to follow the same rules for piano. But, are there any rules or guidelines for writing piano arrangements specifically?

Sorry if this has already been answered

Comment: You don't need to follow any rules, unless you want to.

Comment: Welcome! One of the difficulties of answering this is that piano is used in many, many different kinds of music (19th-century romantic, jazz, rock, new age, honky tonk...). They all have their own conventions, if not "rules." It might help get a more useful answer if you can edit to say more about the kind of writing you're planning.

Comment: If you could also post where you saw people say this (for instance, on this site, or somewhere else?), that might help. Maybe there was a miscommunication or misinterpretation of the original.

Comment: Anything that requires 11 or more fingers to play is probably wrong.

Answer (score 4):

When people talk about four part harmony they usually talk about a theoretical theory of voice leading. This is tool you have at your dispense when you need it. Understanding the rules of four part harmony may help you understand why certain things sound weird, and give you an understanding of how one can improve such things.

But that’s it. When composing it is your choice to make use of these tools or do things differently. But still it helps to know the rules and break them by intent rather than not knowing the rules and breaking them by accident.

For instance compare these two examples:

[image]

Both totally break the traditional rules of voice leading, but the second one sounds fine, while the first sounds a bit awkward. Knowing the rules will help you understand **why** that sounds awkward, and will allow you to make it less awkward.

Answer (score 2):

The four part harmony "rules" you are thinking of are historically about how the Church composed sacred music, choral music. Over centuries of musical style changes those rules carried over into secular, instrumental music with varying degrees of strictness.

To give you some perspective about those historical changes think of someone like Handel and hist sacred choral music as the epitome of proper four part harmony. Compare Handel to Chopin. I was recently playing some dances of Chopin and took note of the very obvious places where he abandoned the old part writing conventions and wrote completely undisguised parallel octaves. That takes us back 150 years from present when the old style was already being abandoned by European composers who largely followed a harmony style develop another 150 years prior. That's a long history of influence and change! We need to be careful about applying "rules" from that long history and the potential to misunderstand them.

Four part harmony rules are not the rules of all music, only the rules of a particular style. That style was very, very popular for a long time. Aspects of that harmonic style are still found in various music styles today.

A general "rule", technically a music texture, that you should be aware of is *homophonic* texture, which is a melody supported by chords. In homophonic style the bass part moves in large part by chord roots and has a contour (shape of a melodic line) which is characteristically different than the main melody. Instead of thinking about the old four part vocal harmony rules you can think about writing good melody lines, good bass lines, and the chords that support both.

Melody and bass can be filled in with chords. In a lot of styles those chords are played on keyboard or guitar. For this you should be aware of basic voice leading which is a carry over of some of the old four part harmony rules. Basic voice leading makes chord changes by moving "voices" of chords by single steps. You can generally categorize three types of movements by how many voice change in triadic harmony.

[image]

Notice I marked with `*` two voice leading options that don't move by single steps. I included them, because they are common and provides alternatives to move the voices either up or down.

Most chord play on keyboard and guitar uses those patterns or variations of them.

Take note of the root progressions that result from the voice leading patterns. This small number of voice leading patterns covers root progressions by fifth/fourth, third/sixth, and second/seventh which is all of the simple intervals. In other words you can use these patterns for any diatonically based chord progression, most common chord progressions.

I'm not specifically covering seventh chords, but if you fill in the missing sevenths for all of the triads in those example patterns you will find that the number of *voices moved* stays the same and the root progressions stay the same.

This provides a short hand, cheat sheet level of voice leading guidelines and actually covers a fair amount of how strict four part writing works. It doesn't include things like doubling tones and handling tendency tones, but that is the kind of stuff abandoned in non-strict and pop styles of harmony.

Arranging would treat these chord/voice leading patterns as a skeleton, just a framework, that could be played with various rhythmic patterns. You could play them as broken chords, arpeggios, decorated with passing tones, etc. etc. Depending on whether the music is piano solo or an ensemble you might add a bass part. A melody, like a vocal part, could be added, but in many cases the rhythmic elaboration of the chord framework becomes the main melody.

> Okay so i recently discovered writing in 4 part harmony and now i'm really confused, i saw people say that you don't need to follow the same rules for piano.

There are no rules. Not really. But there are "conventions" for well defined styles.

Even if you aren't following strict four part harmony rules, most homophonic music, which includes lots of pop styles, use basic voice leading patterns.